# Is it possible to add a margin to the atScrollPosition argument on the scrollToItemAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an app with a horizontal UICollectionView. The cells are arranged full height in one horizontal row so it is only possible to scroll horizontally. There is a menu with shortcuts to scroll to a particular cell. This works fine with the following method:

```
    [myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]
                             atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft
                                     animated:YES];
```

However using the UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft constant will position the cell glued to the left edge of the view. Is there any way to add a margin to the left of the cell? Ideally the same amount specified with minimumInteritemSpacing in the collection view's layout.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding you here, but it sounds like you wish for the cell to be centered after its been scrolled to. For this you can use `UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally` instead of `UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft`.

```
[myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]
                         atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                                 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't want the cell centred I want it left aligned with a left margin. Here is an illustration that might help. Cell X is the one being scrolled to. Using UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft results in the top illustration: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbak7sgx3sqcfum/uiscrollview.jpg

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by increasing the width of the cell and moving everything within the cell to the right, basically adding padding to the cell instead of a left-margin.

Not ideal for certain cases, but in my case it does the job. Hope this helps someone else.